# Tkinter does not run the function

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make use Tkinter. When running my program, a pop up with a button should appear. After pressing the button, the code is executed and the site is parsed. The parsing itself is working ok, but with Tkinter it does not. Besides, the code is executed before a button is pressed. I would be very grateful if someone could point to the mistake I made.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def news():
    page = requests.get('http://www.globo.com/index.html')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    bbb = soup.find_all('p', class_='hui-premium__title')
    for item in bbb:
        ccc = item.get_text('p')
        print(ccc)


from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

b = Button(master, text="latest news", command='news()')
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use HTML to manually format your code. Just paste it, select it, and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. This indents it by 4 spaces, telling Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

The `command` attribute must be given a callable function, not a string.

For example:

```
b = Button(..., command=news)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()` from `news()` in the `Button` creation code. You do not want to run the function at the time you create the button. You want to register it for future use.